# JAXB mixing episodes and xjc:javaType in jar library

Tags: java, maven-2, jaxb, jaxb2, jaxb-episode

If got a Java library which other projects depend on (.jar dependancy through Maven). In this library there is an XSD-file which defines some `xs:simpleType`s which are also annotated with `xjc:javaType` elements mapping the simple types to already existing java classes and adapter classes in that library. This all works fine, but now I wanted to create a `xs:complexType`. I let the `org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin` version 0.8.2 create some java beans from the complex type and an addition .episode file.

In my second project I import the library, unpack the xsd file into a schema directory and let  project2.xsd import the library.xsd, because it uses the simple and complex types. To avoid double generation of already existing beans, I added the libary as an depenancy in the `episodes` tag of the `org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin`. But now the plugin complains that it can't parse the xsd file and throws an exception on every type defintion line.

I presume there is some issue with using episodes (they don't include simpleTypes?) and `xjc:javaType` annotations? Is there some kind of workaround to this problem? I can't find much on the web regarding this issue. Grateful for any hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've achieved the same thing by using maven-hyperjaxb3-plugin
Check how is done:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.hyperjaxb3</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-hyperjaxb3-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.5.4</version>
                <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>id1</id>
                    <inherited>false</inherited>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <args>
                            <param>-npa</param>
                        </args>
                        <generateDirectory>target/generated-sources/xjc2</generateDirectory>
                        <generatePackage>com.target.package</generatePackage>
                        <extension>true</extension>
                        <schemaIncludes>
                            <include>mine.xsd</include>
                        </schemaIncludes>
                        <forceRegenerate>false</forceRegenerate>
                        <removeOldOutput>true</removeOldOutput>
                        <verbose>true</verbose>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
</executions>
<dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
                        <version>2.1.12</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
```

here are the project dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.hyperjaxb3</groupId>
            <artifactId>hyperjaxb3-ejb-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>0.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Roundtrip -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.hyperjaxb3</groupId>
            <artifactId>hyperjaxb3-ejb-roundtrip
            </artifactId>
            <version>0.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

I have any kind of simple and complex types defined and it works like a charm.
Hope it helps!